# Can you enforce exhaustiveness of Map keys in scala?

Tags: scala

Let's assume we have a map indexed by enum values like this

```
sealed trait A
case object B extends A
case object C extends A

type SafeMap = Map[A, String]
```

Would it be possible to somehow enforce the exhaustiveness of such map?
Maybe with dependent types? If not in Scala than Idris is interesting as well.

To clarify, I would like to have a generic constraint for any ADT that check that Map has an entry defined for each variant of ADT.

Comment: I dont realy get your problem. Do you want to be sure the Map contains at least one key of each type ? Then, do you forget to extends A in B and C ?

Comment: My mistake, sorry.

Comment: Still not sure, do you want your Map to have at least one B key and one C key or just to have C or B keys ?

Comment: I would like to have all variants, so both B and C. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: beside my answer. I thin Idris has a totallity checker for something like `A =>String`

Answer (score 4):

well a `Map[A,String]` for an ADT `A` is pretty much a function `A => String`

You can do

```
def foo(a:A):String = a match {
    case ...
}
```

with the fatal-warning flag for the compiler (else non-exhaustive patternmatches are only warnings) this should get you pretty far.

PS: you should probably make your case classes/object final

Comment: This is as close as one can easily get, but not perfect. If I pass `A => String` around I lose much of information.